# Get human-readable name of default keyboard (not package name)

Tags: android, keyboard

Is there a possibility in Android (API 24 - 29) to get the human-readable name of the current default keyboard? When I use the following code

```
String keyboard = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.DEFAULT_INPUT_METHOD);
```

I'm getting

> com.google.android.inputmethod.latin/com.android.inputmethod.latin.LatinIME

But I would like to have `Gboard` instead (i.e. the name that is displayed in the keyboard selection menu and not the package name).

Comment: Something like this, possibly: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FzDwrFsbbeDeAPnyQW-Wnc1ZHxiTfsDW/view?usp=drivesdk. I can't really test that, atm.

Comment: @MikeM. Wow, I just tested it. It seems to work perfectly. Please add it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That result is the `String` form of a `ComponentName`, so we can use the `unflattenFromString()` method to easily parse out the package name, and then retrieve the package's label – i.e., the human-readable name – from its `ApplicationInfo` obtained with `PackageManager`. For example, in a simple Java utility method:

```
public static CharSequence getCurrentImeLabel(Context context) {
    CharSequence readableName = null;

    String keyboard = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), DEFAULT_INPUT_METHOD);
    ComponentName componentName = ComponentName.unflattenFromString(keyboard);
    if (componentName != null) {
        String packageName = componentName.getPackageName();
        try {
            PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
            ApplicationInfo info = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0);
            readableName = info.loadLabel(packageManager);
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return readableName;
}
```

And an equivalent Kotlin extension on `Context`:

```
fun Context.getCurrentImeLabel() : CharSequence? {
    val keyboard = Settings.Secure.getString(contentResolver, DEFAULT_INPUT_METHOD)
    return ComponentName.unflattenFromString(keyboard)?.let {
        packageManager.getApplicationInfo(it.packageName, 0).loadLabel(packageManager)
    }
}
```

---

If all you need is that human-readable name, then this seems to be the most direct approach, as `InputMethodManager` doesn't appear to have any public method that returns the current IME.

However, if you need additional IME-specific information, it seems that it will have to be pulled from the `List<InputMethodInfo>` returned from `InputMethodManager`'s `getInputMethodList()` or `getEnabledInputMethodList()` methods. In both cases, you would need to iterate over the `List`, checking for which `InputMethodInfo#getId()` equals that `String` returned from `Settings`.

The `InputMethodInfo` class also has a `loadLabel(PackageManager)` method available, so if you're using this method, or otherwise have the necessary `InputMethodInfo` already, then you can use that directly, rather than making an unnecessary `getApplicationInfo()` call.